# Программный переход по ссылке

Tags: gwt, java

У меня есть объект класса Hyperlink. Я хочу , чтобы для перехода по ссылке использовалась кнопка, а не ссылка, т.е. реакцией на клик по кнопке был переход по ссылке.

```
final Hyperlink link = new Hyperlink(name, name);
Button btn = new Button(link.getHTML());
btn.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {            
    @Override
     public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
         Window.open("#"+link.getText(), null, null);               
     }
});
```

Этот код работает, но открывает новое окно обозревателя. Как сделать так, чтобы переход был в текущем окне? Может можно надо передать событие для ссылки?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Странно передавать null как параметр открытия страницы, в этом случае вообще результат непредсказуем.

```
Window.open(link, "_self", "");
```

Hyperlink - устаревший класс, лучше использовать [Anchor](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.1/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Anchor.html):

```
Anchor anchor = new Anchor();
anchor.setTarget("_self");
anchor.setHref(link);
```

Ни в коем случае из-за такой проблемы не стоит начинать писать нативный код!

Answer (score 2):

Вместо

```
Window.open("#"+link.getText(), null, null);
```

использовать

```
window.location.replace(link.getText())
```

Comment: согласен! Только вроде бы Window.Location...